# Google Calendar PHP Api - Check if user has edit rights

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-client

I have a web site to which user can grant access to edit their Google Calendars.
On the main page of the site a list of events from a company calendar is shown, the events are editable.

The thing is that all users on the site doesn't have rights to edit events in the calender (their Google Account, that is). Is there any way to check if a user has rights to edit a calendar via the [PHP API client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)?
To clarify, all users shouldn't have permission to edit the calendar. If their Google account has access, the edit tools should the shown. Otherwise they just get the event list.

In this case the calendar is public so everyone should be able to see the events. 
(It wouldn't hurt if it would work with a non-public calendar as well, but I guess that is trickier. Requiring a fallback service account or something.)

I'm currently using the [list method](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) of the [Events Resource](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events) to get the events.

Answer (score 3):

[Calendar list get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/get) returns a [calendar list resource](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList#resource)

which has something called access role

accessRole  string  The effective access role that the authenticated user has on the calendar. Read-only.

Possible values are:

- "freeBusyReader" - Provides read access to free/busy information.
- "reader" - Provides read access to the calendar. Private events will appear to users with reader access, but event details will be hidden.
- "writer" - Provides read and write access to the calendar. Private events will appear to users with writer access, and event details will be visible.
- "owner" - Provides ownership of the calendar. This role has all of the permissions of the writer role with the additional ability to see and manipulate ACLs.

The php code is something like this:

```
calendarListEntry = $service->calendarList->get('calendarId');
```

Note: using a service account would be much easier then the script would have access to the calendar and you could use the script to edit the calendar with out needing access to the users accounts.

Comment: I'm using [listEvents](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) to get the events. The request always seems to return accessRole "reader", regardless of the users permission. Why is this? Is it using my Google Application when checking permissions? 

I want it to use the users Google Account, some users should have permissions to edit the calendar, and some not. I don't want to have to set it up both at Google Calendar and at my site.

Comment: I will have to check the list later.  But by using a service account you can control it all via your site

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the access roles information.

```
        // list all user calendars
        $calendars = $this->service->calendarList->listCalendarList();
        var_export($calendars);
        
        // list specific calendar
        $ca = $this->service->calendarList->get($cid);
        $role = $ca->getAccessRole();
        if ($role != 'writer' || $role != 'owner') {
            // cannot write
            $errorRightsInfo[] = '#'.$ca->getId().' - '.$ca->getSummary(). ' &hellip; '.$role;
        }
    }
```